# Look up keys in a javascript object and return a result

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object

I have the following algorithm where I pass in an array, I count how many of each number is in the array. Then i need to return a result based on the number of times each number appears in the array. The results don't change so I created a look up table which can be found in my `scoreResults` object below:

```
  const scoreResults  = {
    1: {
      1:100
      3:1000
    },
    2: {
      3: 200
    },
    3: {
      3:300
    },
    4: {
      3:400
    },
    5: {
      3:500
      1:50
    },
    6: {
      3:600
    },
  }


 // example dice [2,3,6,6,6]
function score(dice) {
[...]
  return getResult(mapping); // mapping = {2:1, 3:1, 6:3}
}

function getResult(object){
 for (const key in object){

[CODE I CANNOT FIGURE OUT]

 }
 
}
```

For the part I cannot figure out I would like to do the following:

I would now like to check each key in my `mapping` object. For example let's take key value pair `6:3` in my `mapping` object. If key `6` is in my `scoreResults` object (which it is) check the `value` of key 6 in my mapping object (which is 3) if it's 3 then check if there is a key 3 here , within the 6 key:`6: {3:600},` return 600 (the value) if not, return nothing.

Another example:
For the key value pair `2:1` in my `mapping` object I want to see if key `2` is in my `scoreResults` object (which it is) check what the `value` of key `2` in my mapping object is which is `1`, there is no `1` in value of key `2` in my `scoreResults` so return nothing.

Basically I am trying to resolve this algorithm: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5270d0d18625160ada0000e4/train/javascript

Let me know if you need additional clarification

Comment: You just described what your code must do. Try to write down the code following your sentences. `If key 6 is in my scoreResults object` --> `if(scoreResults[6])` for example

Comment: Can you please accept an answer. These answers are clearly solve this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution. You can create array from keys of an object with Object.keys. Just like i did in here also,you can use a parameter instead of mapping object which i pre-defined.

```js
const scoreResults  = {
    1: {
      1:100,
      3:1000
    },
    2: {
      3: 200
    },
    3: {
      3:300
    },
    4: {
      3:400
    },
    5: {
      3:500,
      1:50
    },
    6: {
      3:600
    },
  }


let mapping = {2:1, 3:1, 6:3}

function getResult(){
    let result;
    const keys = Object.keys(mapping);
    keys.map(key => {
        if(scoreResults[key][key]) {
            result = scoreResults[key][key];
        }
    })
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work for any scoreResults and number of dices you could do something like this:

```
function getResult(mapping) {
    let res = 0
    for (let key of Object.keys(mapping)) {
        if (!scoreResults[key])
             continue
        let count = mapping[key]
        let test = count
        while (count > 0 && test > 0) {
            if (scoreResults[key][test]) {
                let amount = Math.floor(count / test)
                res += amount * scoreResults[key][test]
                count -= amount * test
                test = count
            } else {
                test--
            }
        }
    }
    return res
}
```